# What Constitutes a Decreasing Interval?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem:

> For what values of $x$ is $f(x)=x^4-4x^3$ increasing? decreasing?

The first half of the answer in the book is:

> if $x<3$, $f'(x)\leq 0$ and $f$ is decreasing

There is also a note:

> Note that $f$ is decreasing at $x=0$ even though $f'(0)=0$

If $f'(0)=0$, then $f$ at $x=0$ is neither increasing nor decreasing. So why is the book saying what it's saying?

Comment: Maybe it refers to the "general trend" around $x=0$, because there is an interval around $x=0$, but not including $x=0$, where the derivative is negative. The derivative is not positive in an interval around $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To speak about decreasing or increasing, we do not need the derivative to even *exist*!
Recall that $f$ is called (strictly) decreasing on an interval $I$ if for all $x,y\in I$ with $x<y$, we have $f(x)>f(y)$.
We call $f$ decreasing at $x_0$ if it is decreasing on an open interval containing $x_0$.

*If* the derivative $f'(x_0)$ exists, then it is *sufficient* for $f$ to be decreasing at $x_0$ that $f'(x_0)<0$ and it is *necessary* that $f'(x_0)\le 0$.
The case that $f'(x_0)=0$ needs special attention. In your specific example, the MVT may come in handy.

Comment: why does interval $I$ have to be an open interval?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $f$ is strictly decreasing on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2$ in $I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$.

Consider the interval $(-1, 1)$ that contains $0$.

Since $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3$, $f(0) = 0$.

If $-1 < x < 0$, then $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 = x^3(x - 4)$ is the product of two negative numbers, so it is positive.  Hence, $f(x) > f(0)$, which means the function decreases between $x$ and $0$.

If $0 < x < 1$, then $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 = x^3(x - 4)$ is the product of a positive number and a negative number, so it is negative.  Hence, $f(0) > f(x)$, which means the function decreases between $0$ and $x$.

Putting the two observations together, we see that $f$ is decreasing at $x = 0$, as shown in the graph below.

[image: graph of f(x) = x^4 - 4x^3 on the interval (-1, 1)]

Comment: "If $f′(x)<0$ at each point in an interval I, then the function is said to be decreasing on I" This statement is wrong then???

Comment: **Definition.** A function $f$ is said to be *strictly decreasing* on an interval $I$ if for each $x_1, x_2 \in I$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$.  **Theorem.** If $f'(x) < 0$ at each point in an interval $I$, then the function is strictly decreasing on $I$.  The theorem can be proved from the definition.  It is true.  However, observe that the hypothesis is not satisfied since there is a point in the interval where $f'(x) \geq 0$.  This example shows that it is possible for a function to be decreasing on an interval even if there is a point in the interval where $f'(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the derivative of $f$ on both sides of $0$ is decreasing, the function is also decreasing at that point.

If the signs of the derivatives differed, it would be a maximum/minimum.

Comment: the derivative being decreasing is irrelevant, what if the derivative is decreasing but positive?